# Start Menu groups randomly change position

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am having a very annoying issue with Windows 10. The groups in my Start Menu are usually organised vertically, basically stacked on top of each other.

[image: normal start menu]

However, every now and then, Windows decides that it's time to mix things up and expands my Start Menu to the side to fit everything next to each other.

[image: I didn't ask for this]

I can just resize the Start Menu to make the groups stack again, but it's one of those things that just gets annoying over time.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft account, and do you log into more than one computer with it?  Perhaps it's syncing your settings with another computer you use (with a different resolution)?

Comment: I am using a Microsoft account to login, I also login on my laptop with the same account. both my desktop and laptop have the same resolution (1920x1080) and an identical start menu layout. 

I've never had this happen to me on my laptop, it's always the desktop that does it.